# Jump to section when scrolled just a little bit - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scroll

sorry for the lame title. I'm looking for solution to use on my website in react, that contains a few sections that are 100vh of height. Case: when user scrolls just a little bit the page scrolls to the next or previous section depending on the scroll direction.

Kind of like [here](https://d4nyll.github.io/smartscroll/#scrollbar)

Edit: this is not anchor menu case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example using the css `scroll-snap` feature. It's the best solution for me since you do not need to do much or use any external codes.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

/* All the snapping stuff */
.scroll-container {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}

/* Other styles */
section {
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: darkorchid;
}

section:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: turquoise;
}

section:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<main class="scroll-container">
    <section>
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
    </section>
</main>
```

Here is a link to other options that could just work for you: https://24ways.org/2019/beautiful-scrolling-experiences-without-libraries/

Answer (score 3):

ok, I will try to help you

window.scrollTo(x, y) - scrolls the page to the specified coordinate relative to the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [FullPage js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) or [Swaper js](https://swiperjs.com/) to make single pages with section by section scroll

hope useful :)

Comment: Thank you! FullPage illustrates exactly what I'm after (if my leader will agree to pay, we will use this one). However I have used swiper before and never thought to use it in this case. Not sure if it will work with scroll event, can you tell?

Comment: swaper js is great ,  check this : https://swiperjs.com/demos#mousewheel-control | @Bambi007